# Does experience earned vary when you kill enemies from a vehicle?

Tags: borderlands-2

Sometimes, it's way easier to kill enemies from a vehicle than on foot with your little guns.  But do you earn the same amount of experience ?
If you earn more xp on foot than from a vehicle, will it work to damage an enemy from a vehicle and THEN finish him on foot ?

Comment: oops my bad, that was for BL1, disregard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, from experience, you earn less XP from killing enemies in a vehicle.  It's orders of magnitude different.

You can damage an enemy from a vehicle and kill them on foot and get the "non-vehicle" XP for the kill.  I've done this before in co-op, when I would hop out of a vehicle and my partner would stay on the turret, dealing damage.  The game appears to only care about the killing blow.

Comment: It has been this way since BL1.  I think the only exception to this is killing an enemy that's also in a vehicle, you'll get full experience regardless.

Comment: On a side note, amp shields like The Bee also boost bullets fired from the vehicle if the driver is wearing it. At least they do on the 360. I don't play PC or PS3 so i cannot say if they do too.

So the light machine gun runner can actually out DPS a rocket launcher car.